# Futures prices on BBG

Tags: python, bloomberg

Error message:

> Cannot find exchange info for ZSIU3 INDEX'

code:

```
from xbbg import blp
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

blp.bdib('ZSIU3 INDEX',  '2023-07-05 00:00:00',ref = 'EUX-Eurex')
```

(mentioned in the index in ref section of the above command using BBG)

anyone knows a better way to get the prices?

code:

```
from xbbg import blp
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
blp.bdib('ZSIU3 INDEX',  '2023-07-05 00:00:00',ref = 'EUX-Eurex')
```

Comment: executing your code gives the error `NameError: name 'blp' is not defined`  Did you forget to import the libraries?

Comment: I'm telling the error that **I** am getting when executing your code. Are you sure you posted a reproducible example of your code? Because when I execute it, it throws me an error

Comment: your libraries please?

Comment: edited my code for libraries

Comment: are you sure "ZSIU3" is a valid index name? Looking ZSIU3 in google doesn't show much relevant results. Can you provide more information about this particular index?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki It's a perfectly valid Bloomberg ticker (though expired).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure there are similar questions with answers on SO, but at the risk of duplication ...

The `bdib` function in `xbbg` tries to take away the complexity of specifying timezones when asking for intra-day data. The underlying Bloomberg API only deals with UTC times. `xbbg` uses an "exchange" string to identify the timezone and hours of operation.

`xbbg` has a number of configuration files in the package directory (`your_python_install/Lib/site-packages/xbbg/markets`) one of which is `exch.yml`. If you look in this file, you will see entries in the form:

```
FuturesCBOE:
  tz: America/New_York
  allday: [1800, 1700]
```

Every exchange you want to use should have an entry in this file. The as-supplied file does not include "EUX-Eurex" (hence the error you get), so you have to add it yourself, and give it a name (I've used the existing pattern, but you can choose what you want).

```
FuturesEuropeEurex:
  tz: Europe/Berlin
  allday: [210, 2200]
```

(I realize Eurex is in Frankfurt but it seems `xbbg` only understands capital cities).

The `allday` session is the default, and you can get this info from Bloomberg, which tells me the exchange hours (for `EUX-Eurex`) are 02:10-22:00.

**Depending on where you have installed Python** you may need Admin privilege to edit `exch.yml` and also the first time you run your code (as the file gets "pickled" into the cache).

If you add this entry, then this code will work:

```
from xbbg import blp
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
blp.bdib('ZSIU3 INDEX', datetime(2023,7,5),ref = 'FuturesEuropeEurex')
```

and yield something like:

```
ZSIU3 INDEX
open    high    low close   volume  num_trds    value
2023-07-05 11:10:00+02:00   7xxx.0  7xxx.0  7xxx.0  7xxx.0  1   1   7xxx.0
2023-07-05 11:16:00+02:00   7xxx.0  7xxx.0  7xxx.0  7xxx.0  1   1   7xxx.0
2023-07-05 12:39:00+02:00   7xxx.0  7xxx.0  7xxx.0  7xxx.0  24  1   1xxx.0
2023-07-05 13:28:00+02:00   7xxx.0  7xxx.0  7xxx.0  7xxx.0  30  1   2xxx.0
2023-07-05 13:29:00+02:00   7xxx.0  7xxx.0  7xxx.0  7xxx.0  15  1   1xxx.0
2023-07-05 13:40:00+02:00   7xxx.0  7xxx.0  7xxx.0  7xxx.0  28  1   2xxx.0
```

**NB** Bloomberg only stores 6 months of intraday data, so you may need to change dates and/or tickers to run this sample. *One drawback of `bdib` as implemented* is that you can only retrieve one day of data at a time, even though the Bloomberg API allows the specification of start and end UTC datetimes. So it is swings and roundabouts depending on your use-case.

As an aside, you can map tickers to exchanges using the `assets.yml` file but you will still need the exchange info.

Comment: this works! Thanks

Comment: @ridz Good news. Please "tick" the answer as working, to help others searching on a similar topic.

Comment: Just did it. One quick follow-up question. What if I want LDN timing for intraday trades ? I tried using the function in one of your ans: bdibMultiDay(ticker,start_date,end_date,typ,tz,interval=1,session_open=None, session_close=None): I changed the timezone from Asia/Kolkata to Europe/london for 'BHP AU Equity' ,start_date = datetime(2023,10,10,9,15),andend_date = datetime(2023,10,11,15,30) . But it does not seem to work for me -- it returns an empty dataset. –

Comment: @ridz The timezone you want to specify is the TZ of the exchange. So you have asked for prices for the period 09:15 to 15:30 LONDON time: when all good Aussie dealers are in bed/pub. For ASX try `Australia/Sydney`. These are the possible cities: https://gist.github.com/heyalexej/8bf688fd67d7199be4a1682b3eec7568. The function converts back to your local timezone (which will depend on where you are).

Comment: Thanks -- I do get the data when I specify the timezone as Australia/Sydney. But the data  would then be in the local time of Australia/Sydney, and not reflecting the LDN times. Also, when you mentioned , 'bdib function in xbbg tries to take away the complexity of specifying timezones when asking for intra-day data' -- does that mean it shows prices based on GMT?

Comment: Apols: there is no conversion, you just get UTC times. You can use the Exchange Profile information from Bloomberg (ASX Exchange <Go>) which will give you the open/close times in your local time. I'm in London, so the page says open 00:00, close 06:00. Alternatively transform the times in the dataframe to London time yourself.

Comment: thanks for your help!One Quick Q-- is there an alternative solution you know of wherein I get the intraday prices for future even  if ref is not defined in the assets. yml file?